# how do i set up eclipse to run with tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://blog.sencide.com/2011/06/create-web-service-using-apache-axis2.html). It says to go to "There go to Windows –-> Preferences and Select the Server --> Runtime Environments." I don't see Windows Preferences (I am using OS X 10.7.5 on a mac), but when I click Eclipse Preferences I get a very similar menu. (I am using Helios, just like in the tutorial). Even though the menu that I see is very similar, I still don't see an option for "server" like in the tutorial. What should I do to complete step 1.3 in the tutorial? (Basically configure Eclipse to work with tomcat).

This is the menu that I see:

[image: This is the menu that I see]

Comment: Looks like you need to download Eclipse for Java EE Developers.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for help. something went off trying to set this up and just going to redo the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have downloaded `eclipse` for `javase` download **[eclipse for `javaee`](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1)**